# How can I scatter an object array using MPI.NET

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, scatter

I'm trying to scatter a 2d boxed array.
here is the summerized code:

```
using (new MPI.Environment(ref args))
{    
    Intracommunicator comm = Communicator.world;
    object[] boxedArrays = new object[] { };

    if (comm.Rank == 0)
    {
        [... //some initialization ]
        boxedArrays = new object[comm.size];
        for (int p = 0; p < comm.Size; p++)
        {
            [...  //some code to init the array]
            boxedArrays[p] = array;
        }
    }
object myChunk= comm.Scatter(boxedArrays, 0); 
var myArray = (int[,])myChunk;
}
```

When I print myArray it's empty.I tried the other variation of the scatter method but they also didn't work.

I'm using [mpi.net sdk](http://www.osl.iu.edu/research/mpi.net/) with [Microsoft HPC Pack 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39961).

Answer (score 1):

**Scattering messages in MPI.NET**

An array of integers is scattered to all ranks, from the rank 0:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (MPI.Environment environment = new MPI.Environment(ref args))
        {
            Intracommunicator comm = Communicator.world;

            if (comm.Rank == 0)
            {
                int [] numbers = new int[comm.Size];

                for (int k = 0; k < numbers.Length; k++)
                    numbers[k] = k * k;

                int r = comm.Scatter(numbers);

                Console.WriteLine("Received {0} at {1}", r, comm.Rank);
            }
            else
            {
                int r = comm.Scatter<int>(0);
                Console.WriteLine("Received {0} at {1}", r, comm.Rank);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's been a long time since when I was working on that MPI program. I have to spent some time on this to refresh my knowledge. So for the time being I just Upvote the answert.

Comment: thanks for upvoting. Your question was ranked high in google results so I thought this might help others